# VB.net Unable to access a dll during a build

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference

I've got a program with three projects. One of them called businessCode, is a Application type Class Library, and the other two businessAuto and businessManual are windows forms.

I should be able to call businessCode from both the other projects. I've added my dll to both the  Auto and Manual bins and added references. I've set my dependencies so both the windows for are dependent on the businessCode project. I've checked and made all my modules in businessCode to Public Module.

However, when I try to build my code, every reference to the dll businessCode comes back with "businessCode" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Error occurs during the build.

Snip- it

```
'*****Will return error****
'businessCode' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
 businessCode.basMain.Main(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to start over.
I made a new empty project and copied code. Once I copied everything over, I built the new businessCode. It built correctly then I added the Auto project. I had to manually copy my dll from the businessCode folder to the auto bin then I set added a reference to the dll in the Auto bin. Otherwise it would give me the same reference did not exist error. I did the same with manual.

I don't know why the same steps didn't work in my old solution but starting a new solution seems to of resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the error have 'BussinessCode' and BussienssCode?
I would check to make sure that you are spelling the class names correctly.

Comment: No, sorry I just can't spell. Now fixed above.

Comment: Have you set the Start-up project as either businessManual or businessAuto?

Comment: I've tried both. At one point I was able to build an run from auto. Then I started adding code to manual that's when the issue started